# Relative velocity of spinors in spinor geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, spinors

So I'm trying to understand [spinor geometry](https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/Spin/SpinNotes.pdf) (and not getting anywhere).

Is it possible to define relative velocity for spinors? (at a point in the manifold similar to [How to calculate relative velocity in curved spacetime?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/646149/how-to-calculate-relative-velocity-in-curved-spacetime))  If so, how?

This question was inspired by this:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2281305/430082

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "relative velocity for spinors". What about relative velocity (as treated in the question you link) is "for non-spinors" so that you need a different notion "for spinors"? Relative velocity is just about a way to compare two velocities, which are vectors, at different points. Do you perhaps mean that you're looking for ways to compare two different *spinors* at different points? (I don't see why one would call that relative *velocity* for spinors - what do spinors have to do with velocities?) Why do you need such a way?

Comment: Hi More Anonymous. Echoing @ACuriousMind: In which context? Is this question inspired by some reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic I've linked the square root of the line element  - link which inspired this question. Even an answer explaining why this can't be done will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a spinor *field*, there may be ways to obtain a natural velocity vector. For a Dirac field for example, there is the conserved Dirac current vector field $\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi$, which is timelike and future-pointing. You can then normalise it to obtain a 4-velocity vector field. You can compare this velocity (field) to any other velocity, in a standard way. (This answer should be treated as preliminary thoughts, and feedback is welcomed.)