# Relative velocity and proper time derivative of geodesic deviation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics, relative-motion

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation)

> To quantify geodesic deviation, one begins by setting up a family of closely spaced geodesics indexed by a continuous variable s and parametrized by an affine parameter $\tau$. That is, for each fixed $s$, the curve swept out by $\gamma _s(\tau)$ as τ varies is a geodesic. When considering the geodesic of a massive object, it is often convenient to choose $\tau$ to be the object's proper time. If $x^μ(s, τ)$ are the coordinates of the geodesic $\gamma_s(\tau)$, then the tangent vector of this geodesic is:
>
> $$ T^\mu = \frac{\partial x^\mu(s,\tau)}{\partial \tau} $$
>
> If $\tau$ is the proper time, then $T_\mu$ is the four-velocity of the object traveling along the geodesic.
> One can also define a deviation vector, which is the displacement of two objects traveling along two infinitesimally separated geodesics:
>
> $$ X^\mu =  \frac{\partial x^\mu(s,\tau)}{\partial s} $$

Now, naively

$$ v^\mu = T^\beta \nabla_\beta X^\mu$$

Should $v^\mu$ be the relative velocity? If so, how does that fit in with this definition of [relative velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/646149/how-to-calculate-relative-velocity-in-curved-spacetime)? (when their geodesics intersect)

> $$
> v:=-\frac{1}{g(u^′,u)} u^′ - u \tag{1}
> $$

I feel I've managed to confuse myself.

Comment: Found a relevant lecture:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEVe0aum0Kg&list=PL7aXC0jU4Qk519AR6zqWYr2VuzLzYUZex&index=4

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you seem to have confused yourself :-)

I edited several of your formulas. Check them out.

The equation

$$ v^\mu = T^\beta \nabla_\beta X^\mu$$

measures the rate of separation between 2 neighboring geodesics, so it measures their relative 4-velocity.
The quoted question and the paper mentioned therein take the matter to a deeper level, however...
you have to realize that the "relative ordinary velocity" of an object passing close to you, regardless if it is moving on a geodesic or not, is simply the spacelike component of its 4-velocity (corrected by a $\gamma$ factor). This assumes that you are using a LIC (locally inertial coordinates system). You are gently guided to this formula in MTW Gravitation Ex. 2.5 page 65 and it coincides with your eq. 1.

So  eq. 1 is simply the gamma corrected projection of the equation $$ v^\mu = T^\beta \nabla_\beta X^\mu$$

You can better see their relation, by observing that - since $X$ and $T$ vectors commute (they form a 2D coordinate system) - you have that
$$ v^\mu = X^\beta \nabla_\beta T^\mu$$ which represent the difference in 4-velocity on neighboring geodesics, similar to eq. 1.
You can read about this in MTW Box 11.4, for example.

Comment: Unlike in equation (1) where u and u' are specified, the quantity $v^{\mu}$ here represents relative velocity b/w which two neighboring tangent vectors? It seems that $v^{\mu}$ only provides the rate of change and not exactly the difference

Comment: Indeed eq 1 shows the difference between 2 generic world lines,  while $v^\mu$ shows the limit of (the difference between infinitesimally close world lines divided by $\Delta s$), so it is a ratio, but the idea is the same. Anyway, when I have more time I will improve the answer