# Lorentz violation in String theory

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, symmetry-breaking, lorentz-symmetry

First of all, why are there so many researches to find Lorentz violation? 
Are there some models of (super-)string theory that include [Lorentz violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_searches_for_Lorentz_violation) at some scale?

Comment: What I've read is that string theory preserves Lorentz symmetry exactly, but other models such us LQG predicts Lorentz violation. And to answer the first question, wouldn't you like to know if our current theories are correct?

Comment: @jinawee has it right. I once read in an article titled something like "Experimental tests that would disprove string theory" that Lorentz violation would be one.

Comment: You are right, but take a look at this: http://www.indiana.edu/~lorentz/sme2012/Berger-1.pdf As I undserstand it is possible to conserve supersymmetry while breaking Lorentz invariance at some high energy..

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17155/2451

Answer (score -1):

An arbitrary string theory doesn't need to break Lorentz symmetry, however some particular string theories can break it. Looking for Lorentz violation is a way to test these particular string theories that can break (spontaneously) Lorentz symmetry.  Other exotic theories such as non-commutative field theories and loop-quantum gravity have also been associated with Lorentz violation. Presently is impossible to probe directly gravity at the quantum level.  If you want to probe gravity at the quantum level you need to look for indirect methods like looking for exotic signals and a breaking of Lorentz symmetry is one of these exotic signals.

Comment: Can you give an example of a string theory that breaks Lorentz symmetry?