# Do black holes have infinite areas and volumes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, volume

How to calculate the area / volume of a black hole?
Is there a corresponding mathematical function such as rotating $1/x$ around the $x$-axis or likewise to find the volume?

Comment: Presumably the area and volumes are that of and inside the event horizon.

Comment: How much do you know about integrating over forms?  Also, the volume of a black hole is coordinate dependent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The event horizon is a lightlike surface, and so its area is coordinate-invariant. For a Schwarzschild black hole,
$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)dt^2 + \left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2)$$
The horizon suface is at $r = 2m$ of Schwarzschild radial coordinate, and so at any particular Schwarzschild time ($dt = 0$) has the metric
$$dS^2 = (2m)^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2),$$
which is just the metric on a standard 2-sphere of radius $2m$. You can find the square area element explicitly as the determinant of the metric, $dA^2 = (2m)^4\sin^2\theta\,d\theta^2d\phi^2$, and integrating:
$$A = 16\pi m^2 = \frac{16\pi G^2}{c^4}m^2.$$

The *volume* of the black hole is not invariant, as Jerry Schirmer says. If you try to apply anything the above Schwarzschild coordinates above, then since the coefficients of $dt^2$ and $dr^2$ switch signs across the horizon, $t$ is spacelike and $r$ is timelike. Therefore, since the black hole is eternal, it could be said to have infinite volume (classically, but a real astrophysical black hole would have a finite but still extraordinarily high lifetime), as you'll be integrating $dt$ across its lifetime.

Technically, the above argument is a bit flawed, because the Schwarzschild coordinate chart is not defined across the event horizon, so one should be more careful how they're continued across the horizon (e.g., with Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates). But this can be made more rigorous.

In another coordinate chart, e.g., the Gullstrand-Painlevé coordinates adapted to a family of freely falling observers,
$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)dt^2-2\sqrt{\frac{2m}{r}}\,dt\,dr + \underbrace{dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2)}_{\text{Euclidean in spherical coord.}},$$
at any instant of time ($dt = 0$), space is precisely Euclidean; since the horizon is still $r = 2m$ in these coordinates, "the" volume is
$$V_{\text{GP}} = \frac{4}{3}\pi(2m)^3.$$

If you pick yet another coordinate chart, you may get a yet different answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you are a Schwarzschild observer the radial co-ordinate $r$ is defined as the circumference of a circle around the black hole divided by $2\pi$. Also the event horizon is at a Schwarzschild radius of $2M$ (in geometrised units), so for a Schwarzschild observer the area of the event horizon is simply $16\pi M^2$.

But this is a somewhat trivial answer as in effect I'm just saying "well that's how we define $r$". I get the impression you're looking for a deeper answer than this, but you'll need to expand on your question a bit.

**Later:**

I've just noticed [Is a black hole's surface area invariant for distant intertial observers?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28064/is-a-black-holes-surface-area-invariant-for-distant-intertial-observers) that states the area of the event horizon is an invarient. This means all observers will measure the area to be $16\pi M^2$.