# Interpretation of black hole area

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, differential-geometry, event-horizon

I'm studying properties of Kerr spacetimes and a lot of fuss is made about area of BH. It is defined to be integral of area element on event horizon $r=r_+$, $t=const.$ where $r_+$ is radial coordinate of outer event horizon. In what way this can be interpreted as actual area of anything? What kind of measuring process would yield as a result this area?

What bothers me is the result we get depends on foliation of spacetime we choose, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The area of an event horizon is an invariant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28064/is-a-black-holes-surface-area-invariant-for-distant-intertial-observers), so it doesn't matter what coordinate system you use to calculate it.

The area is of physical interest because it's proportional to the entropy of the black hole, and in a second law kind of way that means the area cannot decrease.