# Do black holes exhibit length contraction just like anything else being observed moving at high velocity?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes

My intuition is telling me they would experience length contraction the same as anything else but I cannot find anything that says this would be the case.

Comment: FWIW: "length contraction" is not something that things "experience." It's something that _you observe_ when you measure the length of a thing that is flashing past you at relativistic speed. Suppose it's a space ship. You might observe it to be contracted in the direction of its flight, but the crew on the ship won't notice anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking if length contraction applies to the Schwarzschild radius of a black hole that's observed to be traveling at a significant fraction of light speed? Bear in mind that the event horizon itself isn't visible. Also, the effect of length contraction on the appearance of a ball at high speed is complicated due to the time it takes light to travel from the various parts of the ball to the observer, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation

Comment: Ok, my question is asking about the event horizon. Would the black hole appear to flatten as it approaches the speed of light?

Comment: Related, though not a duplicate: [Is a black hole's surface area invariant for distant intertial observers?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28064/is-a-black-holes-surface-area-invariant-for-distant-intertial-observers)

Comment: I'm a bit surprised people are saying this is unclear. In the coordinates of the Schwarzschild observer the event horizon is a sphere. The question is simply in the coordinates of an observer at infinity boosted relative to the Schwarzschild observer is the event horizon still a sphere?