# How can the derivative of this trace be constrained?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

I am studying for my exam on relativity and I am going through some problems sets including ones where I was not very successful in so I want to know how to do this problem.

> (Convergence of particles): Consider a freely falling reference particle in vacuum
>   as in Exercise 1. Assume now in addition that the Hessian matrix of the
>   gravitational potential does not vanish initially in the vicinity of the reference
>   particle. Recall that the displacement of a nearby particle $y(t)$ is given in terms of its initial displacement $y(0)$ (we assume that the particle is intitially at rest relativie to the reference particle) by
>   $$y(t) = A(t)y(0)$$

NOTE: Just to give some context we say that $y(t)$ is a displacement between two freely falling particles positioned $x_{0}(t)$ and $x(t)$ so $y(t) = x(t)-x_{0}(t)$. We can say that a nearby freely falling particle satisfies to first order in y the tidal equations, mainly we can see that:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}y}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=-\nabla^2\psi(x_0(t))\cdot{y(t)}.$$

Back to the problem.

> We call $A$ the deformation matrix. Show that there is an initial displacement $y(0)\neq0$ and a time $t^*>0$ such that $y(t^*)=0$.
>
> Hint. Recall the definition of the strain matrix:
>   $$\theta=\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}A^{-1}.$$

Now to solve this the question breaks it down to several small parts. I was able to solve the first part so I will skip it. But here is the part I am having trouble with:

> (2) Deduce from the tidal equation the following ordinary differential inequality:
>   $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\operatorname{tr}\theta\leq-\frac{1}{3}(\operatorname{tr}\theta)^2$$
>   Hint: Decompose $\theta$ into its diagonal and its traceless part.

NOTE: We deduced from lecture a long time ago that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\operatorname{tr}\theta=-|\theta|^2-\operatorname{tr}M$ where $M=\nabla^2\psi(x_0(t))$ or in other words $M$ is the hessian of the gravitational potential of the particles that are freely falling. We also know that $\operatorname{tr}M=\Delta\psi(x_0(t))$ and in a vacuum this is equal to 0.

So, concerning this problem I figure if we have to break down $\theta$ to a diagonal part and a traceless part that means we can call the diagonal $\sigma$ and the traceless part $\omega$, such that $\theta=\sigma+\omega$. That means that:
\begin{align}
 &\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\operatorname{tr}(\sigma+\omega) \\
 &\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\operatorname{tr}(\sigma) 
\end{align}
Since the trace of the omega is 0 but honestly I am not sure what more to do. I think I actually have to move that derivative and maybe I will be able to get that inequality.

Comment: Hi InsigMath - I edited your question to make it clearer, but please review it and fix anything I messed up.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Yeah that looks good thank you for the edit

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13694/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. OP's trace inequality is the [Focusing Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation#Focusing_theorem) for time-like geodesics in 3+1 dimensions.
2. The two main assumptions to obtain the inequality from the [Raychaudhuri equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation) is i) no vorticity, and ii) the Strong [Energy Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_conditions).

Comment: I have never heard of the Focusing Theorem and we never learned about any energy conditions until later in the course so I don't know whether it would have been fair to have used that idea. Plus we only have learned about the Dominant Energy Condition.